# How to memset for pointer-to-pointer

Tags: c

I’ve been trying to print value of protent structure.

```
struct protoent {
    char  *p_name;       /* official protocol name */
    char **p_aliases;    /* alias list */
    int    p_proto;      /* protocol number */
}
```

My code, following List.c, shows `proto.p_name = (null)` but It ends segmentation fault when it tries to print `p_alliases`.

Does anyone tell me how it happens?

I think memory isn’t allocated to `p_alliases` pointer-to-pointer variable with `memset` or `proto = { 0 }`

Then how can I memset to `p_aliases` and print `proto.p_aliases = (null)`?

List.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int
main(){
        struct protoent proto  ;
        memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));
        printf("proto.p_name = %s\n",proto.p_name);
        printf("proto.p_aliases = %s\n",*proto.p_aliases);
        printf("proto.p_proto = %d\n",proto.p_proto);
}
```

Comment: Of course it will crash, you are de-referencing a pointer that has a null value.  Everything in the structure is 0.

Comment: OldProgrammer is correct. It's this that causes the crash: `*proto.p_aliases`. p_aliases isn't a string so you can't print it directly; if you want to display "(null)" then you need to check for that and code it specifically.

Comment: The name p_aliases and the comment suggest that there could be any number of aliases, but you attempt to print exactly one. Have you considered a possibility of two aliases, or no aliases? How would you account for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memset` statment below is setting all the memory allocated by `proto` to `0`. So `proto.p_aliases` is pointing to `0x000000` then you're tring to dereference it which leads to segmentation fault.

```
memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));
```

`*proto.p_aliases` is the content of the adresse pointed to by `proto.p_aliases` so you cannot print it as the adresse is `NULL`. You can only print the adresse pointed to. So you have to change your print statment to:

```
printf("proto.p_aliases = %s\n", proto.p_aliases); // Not *proto.p_aliases
```

And because you're using the `%s` formating it will print `(null)`.

If you want to use `memset` with `*proto.p_aliases` then you have to allocate memory for it then `proto.p_aliases` is no longer pointing to `NULL`. In this case you can print. Then content of it's adresse.

```
    proto.p_aliases = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    memset(&(*proto.p_aliases), 0, sizeof(*proto.p_aliases));
    printf("*proto.p_aliases %s", *proto.p_aliases);
```

Comment: ＠rullof this code works well but there is warning `assignment from incompatible pointer type` at `malloc`. Any good idea to fix it?

Comment: @user1345414 Sorry just remove the don't cast the returned value of `malloc` as edited. `proto.p_aliases = malloc(sizeof(char *))`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to dereference a null pointer (i.e. the member `char **p_aliases`).

Enclosed is a `print_array` function that will safely print your array of strings, whether or not they have been assigned or freshly zeroed as in your example.  The array is per the spec of `protoent` (i.e. null entry terminating the list).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct protoent {
    char  *p_name;       /* official protocol name */
    char **p_aliases;    /* alias list */
    int    p_proto;      /* protocol number */
};

// print char *array[], final entry (s[n]==null), handles empty list (s==null) also
void print_array(char **s) {
    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; s && s[i]; ++i)
        printf("\"%s\" ", s[i]);
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(){
        struct protoent proto  ;
        memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));

        printf("With freshly zeroed struct:\n");
        printf("proto.p_name = %s\n",proto.p_name);
        printf("proto.p_aliases = ");
        print_array(proto.p_aliases);
        printf("proto.p_proto = %d\n",proto.p_proto);

        char *aliases[] = { "A1", "A2", 0 };
        proto.p_aliases = aliases;
        printf("\nAfter assigning array:\n");
        printf("proto.p_aliases = ");
        print_array(proto.p_aliases);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./nullstr 
With freshly zeroed struct:
proto.p_name = (null)
proto.p_aliases = [ ]
proto.p_proto = 0

After assigning array:
proto.p_aliases = [ "A1" "A2" ]
```

I hope this is helpful.